# Cucumber process / sub process invocation

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Cucumber-JVM.

I have a process and a subprocess. The process calls the subprocess and then continues.

Ideally I want the following scenarios:

```
Scenario: Process
 Given I start a process
 When I have completed the sub process
 And then I complete task A
 And then I complete task B
 Then the process is finished

Scenario: SubProcess
 Given I start a subprocess
 When I complete task C
 And then I complete task D
 Then the process is finished
```

I'm wondering what the best approach is to coding "When I have completed the sub process"

I have read a little about invoking steps from step definitions however they are not supported in cucumber-jvm. Is this the only option available or are there others? Ideally I would invoke the entire scenario instead of a individual step.

Comment: So the SubProcess is also a separate scenario which can work on its own? Can you not duplicate the subprocess steps along with the data inside the process scenario?

Comment: Hey Grasshopper, yes the sub process can work on its own but there are multiple tasks +10 etc which I don't want to maintain in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this won't be the answer you are looking for... but what I do in these cases is creating a 'new' step grouping all the steps involved in the scenario. I know it's not an elegant solution but I think there are not other options in `cucumber-jvm`. See this [closed issue](http://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/502)

Example for your use case:

```
@When("^I have completed the sub process$")
public void I_have_completed_the_sub_process() throws Throwable {
 I_complete_task_C();
 I_complete_task_D();
 the_process_is_finished();
}
```

Then, you can use this new step in the `given` scenario background conditions. Something like that:

```
Background:
 Given I have completed the sub process

Scenario: Process
 Given I start a process     
 And then I complete task A
 And then I complete task B
 Then the process is finished
```

I'll be waiting for other answers, hoping there is a better option.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks troig, the issues with this is that the subprocess is actually a scenario outline which requires configuration that I want to keep in Gherkin and out of Java.

Comment: You're welcome @IanWatson, and you are right. it's a shame cannot reference other scenario...I've made a little edit in my answer, using background. I think it's clearer but your problem will still remains anyway. I'll wait for other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, assuming you want to run the SubProcess only once for the Process, what you are looking for is a table (or a Scenario Outline).

```
 Scenario: Process

 Given I start a process
 When I have completed the sub process "<x>" "<y>" "<z>"
| x |   y | z|
 And then I complete task A
 And then I complete task B
 Then the process is finished
```

or

```
Scenario Outline: Process
 Given I start a process
 When I have completed the sub process "<x>" "<y>" "<z>"
 And then I complete task A
 And then I complete task B
 Then the process is finished
| x |   y | z|

Scenario Outline: SubProcess
 Given I start a subprocess "<x>"
 When I complete task C "<y>"
 And then I complete task D "<z>"
 Then the process is finished
 Examples:
 | x  |  y   |  z   |

@When("^I have completed the sub process (.*) (.*) (.*)$")
public void I_have_completed_the_sub_process(String x, String y, String z) throws Throwable {
  I_start_a_subprocess(x);
  .....
  <your code>;
}
```

you can also have cucumber return all the values in the column as a list

But if this involves a lot of configuration data, you may wanna read the configuration from a datasource like a yaml file and pass the key to the step.

yaml file:

```
:configuration:
    :x: "val1"
    :y: "val2"
    :z: "val3"
```

And your step takes only one input

```
When I have completed the sub process "<configuration>"
```

The step definition parses the hashmap and passes the values to the steps methods as needed.

Or you can have the values as a table, create a class Configuration and the step definition takes a list value as input:
https://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables/

```
public class Config{
private String x,
private String y,
Private String z }

public void step_definition_function(<List>Config config){}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sid but I don't think this will work, the sub process is a scenario with a data table. I don't see how I will be able to execute the scenario with its data table without defining the same data table in the process.

Comment: Hmm..Cucumber doesnt support calling a scenario within another. You will most probably have to pass the same dataset. There are only three ways that I can think of: 1. The data in the table is stored in a datasource like yaml and both yamls take a single column table referring it so all you will need to do is call the same key in both or 2. the config details are directly handled in the step definitions and not the feature file, if you dont want to pass the config in the table. 3. Convert your subprocess into a step.